# How do I delete "Untitled" XCode signing certificates?

Tags: ios, xcode

I removed all of my certificates from Keychain, I removed the account from XCode, I deleted the XCode app, and I even got rid of ~/Library/Developer/XCode.
But, when I reinstall XCode from the AppStore and add my Apple ID to accounts and look at the list of signing certificates for my team, I have this list of "Untitled" certificates that say "Missing Private Key." 
Where is XCode looking to get this list it won't let go of?
How do I get rid of them?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

They should be in the app "Keychain Access," if you haven't tried that yet.

1. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to open Spotlight
2. Type in Keychain Access, then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image: Spotlight search]

3. Find the certificate, then press <kbd>delete</kbd>

[image: Certificate selected]

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I deleted all the certificates in Keychain. I deleted everything I can figure out to delete, but there are some files somewhere that XCode keeps looking at. I've tried everything except wiping the entire Mac which is my next step if someone smarter than me can't figure it out.

Comment: @aheze: Can I ask you something?

Comment: @Paul sure, just click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and me or someone else will take a look. Or you can also find me on my socials linked on my profile

Comment: @aheze: The question is this, if you can take a look at it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438041/xcode-free-provisioning-remove-certificates

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are checking or remove certificate in wrong area.

Please check in the "keychain access" > "Certificates". Not in the "keychain access" > "My Certificates"

Thanks